# RegEx: Comma separated complex groups

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Assume I have a comma separated line:

```
aa,bb,cc
```

I can regex this using (not really ok because this also matches `,aa` but that is not the question here) :

```
(<my pattern>)?(,<my pattern>)*
```

E.g.

```
([a-zA-Z]*)?(,[a-zA-Z]*)*
```

NOW, assume that `<my pattern>` is **very long and complex**, it would be nice if I could say something like:

```
(<my pattern>)?(,<repeat previous/named group>)*
```

Is there a way to say to repeat a certain group (name) (in Python 3.5)

Comment: `<my pattern> is very long and complex` And, so what? Just duplicate it via `(?:[a-zA-Z]+)(?:,?[a-zA-Z])*` Since `<your pattern>` is nothing special, there is no reason to use recursion. Only use recursion if you have a need to balance text (can be anything), because recursion in general, adds considerable overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid such syntactic sugar does not exist in regex, but considering that python uses strings for regex, you can simply use strings formatting to reduce your code:

```
re.findall('({0})?(,{0})*'.format(<your_pattern>), <some_string>)
```

Comment: Such syntactic sugar exists but not in the Python re module. However, it exists in the regex module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex . Note that this module supports also repeated captures. With this feature you can extract and check at the same time.

Comment: It isn't also a "syntactic sugar" since this feature makes the recursion possible and allows to write a pattern as with a lexer.

Answer (score 0):

There are regex engines that support this kind of backreference, but Python's regex engine does not.

However, just because the regex engine doesn't have builtin support for this doesn't mean we can't build a regex pattern that achieves our goal. All we have to do is change the `,` in the regex - instead of looking for a comma, we want to allow a comma **or** the start of the string:

```
((?:,|^)[a-zA-Z]*)*
```